# “I do not know where … is” vs. “I do not know where is …”

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, relative-clauses, subject-verb-inversion

Which of the following sentences is correct in a formal context?  Both?  If possible, please also explain *why* each of these sentences is correct/incorrect.

> I do not know where the best place to ask this question is.
>
> I do not know where is the best place to ask this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The first one is correct in formal and informal contexts.  The second sentence would not be used by a native speaker.

The reason is that there is a difference in the way that English handles [wh-words](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/WH-word), when they are in the main clause vs. when they are in the embedded clause.  The structure also depends on whether the wh-word is the subject or the object in its clause.

In the main clause, we use the basic order: *wh-word verb ______.*

> **Where is** the best place to ask this question?

This is true when the wh-word is the subject or the object, although you'll notice we use [do-support](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support#Questions) when the wh-word is the object (when the main verb is not *is*):

> - Who **told** you that?  (*who* is the subject, no do-support)
> - Who **did** you **tell**? (*who* is the object, use do-support)

When the wh-word is inside of an embedded clause, the verb doesn't move to the front of the clause; only the wh-word moves.  For example:

> - I was wondering [who **told** you]? (corresponds to "who told you?" in main clause)
> - I was wondering [who you **told**]? (corresponds to "who did you tell?" in main clause)

(In other languages, this pattern is not the same; it is an arbitrary feature of English.)

Since *where* is the object in this case (and usually is in general), it follows the second pattern, so: "I do not know where ... is".

Comment: Thanks!  To make sure that I understand the answer, do you mean that the “where” in the question “Where is the best place to ask this question?” is not the subject but the complement?

Comment: "Where" is the object (and not the subject, as you say).

Comment: Thanks.  I will probably accept your answer, but I will wait for any other answer for a day just in case.

Comment: +1 for the interesting answer but I can't help noticing that the English construction is very... Germanic: 1/ **Direct** _Wo **ist** der beste Platz, um diese Frage zu stellen?_" 2/ **Indirect** _"Ich weiß nicht, wo der beste platz, um diese Frage zu stellen **ist** "_.

Comment: I know it's horribly prescriptivist of me, but: "**Whom** did you tell?" and "I was wondering **whom** you told?"  I can still hear the nuns when I close my eyes...  NO!  Not the ruler, I'll get it right next time!

Comment: @Alain Pannetier: Yes, it is quite Germanic! :)

Comment: Part of your answer gives the right explanation, but "the reason is that there is a difference in the way that English handles wh-words" is wrong. As far as you look at the two expressions asked, wh-movement is irrelevant. It is about the presence vs. absence of **verb movement to the front of the clause**.